# How to put data in view scope via EL in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, facelets, view-scope

In my JSF page this works:

```
${requestScope.put('test', 'data')}
${requestScope.get('test')}
```

This causes exception:

```
${viewScope.put('test', 'data')}
${viewScope.get('test')}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:159)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:84)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:157)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:154)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

How do I use other than `requestScope` on JSF page? I can of course have a view scoped bean but I thought I can use the scope variables directly. I have Tomcat 8.0.21 with Mojarra 2.2.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not the right way to put data in a certain scope from the Facelets template on.

You're supposed to use [`<c:set>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/c/set.html) for this.

Putting data in request scope:

```
<c:set var="test" value="data" scope="request" />
..
#{test}
```

Putting data in view scope:

```
<c:set var="test" value="data" scope="view" />
..
#{test}
```

The `scope` attribute also supports `session` and `application`.

Putting data in the [Flash scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getFlash()) is done a bit differently:

```
<c:set target="#{flash}" property="test" value="data" />
...
#{flash.test}
```

Comment: You can safely replace `java.sun.com` by `xmlns.jcp.org` for Java EE 7 / JSF 2.2. See also [JSTL core overview in Facelets VDL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/c/tld-summary.html).